# Why is this loop in Cython as slow as its Python equivalent?

Tags: python-3.x, cython

The following code rearranges bits in an RGBA4 texture data array.

```
cpdef bytes toDDSrgba4(bytearray data):
    cdef bytes new_data = b''
    cdef u32 i, pixel, new_pixel
    cdef u32 red, green, blue, alpha

    for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
        pixel = int.from_bytes(data[i:i+2], "big")

        red = (pixel >> 12) & 0xF
        green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xF
        blue = (pixel >> 4) & 0xF
        alpha = pixel & 0xF

        new_pixel = (red << 8) | (green << 4) | blue | (alpha << 12)
        new_data += (new_pixel).to_bytes(2, "big")

    return new_data
```

However, even with correct variable typing, it is just as slow as its Python equivalent.
What is the cause?

Comment: Maybe put all your `new data` into a list instead of concatenating it at each step, and then join it up at the end.

Comment: OK, I'll try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're appending to a `bytes` object with `+=`. That's really slow, since it has to copy the whole existing `bytes` object every time.

Don't do that. One better option would be to use a `bytearray`, and only build a `bytes` object out of the `bytearray` at the end.

Comment: Wooooooow, it's way way waaaaay faster now, thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

from_bytes and to_bytes way too slow I think. try instead of from_bytes:

```
pixel = (data[2*i]) << 8 | (data[2*i+1])
```

it's really faster then your code, i'v tested it.
but for to_bytes I can't imagine fast version right now.

Comment: Same speed, the whole function takes about 30 seconds to execute.

Comment: It's strange. In python version my code 15% faster. Don't know how to try cyphon.

Comment: I also tried struct.unpack(), but it still is the same as before.

Comment: Like user2357112 said, the problem is that I used +=